# Continuity in metric space, TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ be metric spaces , and let $f: X \to Y$ be a function.
>
> True or false ? Give a proof or a counterexample as appropriate.
>
> $(a)$ If $d$ is the discrete metric on $X$,then $f$ is continuous.
>
> $(b)$ If $U$ open in $(X,d) \Rightarrow f(U)$ open in $(Y,e)$, then $f$ is continuous.
>
> $(c)$ If there exists $r\gt 0$ so that $\,\,\,e(f(x_1),f(x_2)) \le r\,d(x_1,x_2)\,\,$for every $x_1,x_2 \in X$ , then $f$ is continuous. (Dose the converse hold?)

Definition:

- Let $(X, d)$ and $(Y, e)$ be metric spaces, and let$ x \in X$. A
  function $f : X \to Y $is continuous at $x$ if:
  $\forall B \in \mathcal  B(f(x))  \exists  A \in \mathcal  B(x) : f(A) \subseteq B$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the given problem ?

Comment: @Belgi: for (a) I think it is true because every open ball in Y there is an open ball in X with the discrete metric. since all the sets in the discrete metric is open and closed in the same time.
for (b) I think is false but I couldn't think of a counterexample.
for (c) I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

(a) If $d$ is the discrete metric on $X$, what are the open sets in $X$?

(b) Try thinking of a metric on $Y$ that gives *a lot* of open sets (so that the condition will hold). Working out (a) will tell you the metric. Then think about the function (so that it is not continuous).

(c) Think of the "$\epsilon -\delta$" definition of continuity.

Comment: for (a) the open sets are $X$ itself and $\{x\}$ for all $x \in X$

Comment: Yes. So what $A$ do you choose that fulfills the definition?

Comment: $A=\{x\}$...Thank you

Comment: for(b) If $(X,d)$ is the discrete metric on $X$ and $(Y,e)=(\Bbb R,d_{\Bbb R})$ and $f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x \ge 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x \lt 0$}  \\
\end{cases}$ ,Does this work?

Comment: Well, you want "a lot" of open sets in $Y$, not in $X$...